# Representing a function by simplification.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

The concept of 'functions and limits' always seemed confusing to me. I came across this question which occurred to me as a 'basic' of limits.

**Q.** Check whether the following functions are the same:

$f\left(x\right)=log\left(\left(x-2\right)\left(x-3\right)\right)$

and

$g\left(x\right)=log\left(x-2\right)+log\left(x-3\right)$

I jumped upon the conclusion that, as

$log\left(\left(x-2\right)\left(x-3\right)\right)$ = $log\left(x-2\right)+log\left(x-3\right)$

the functions $g\left(x\right)$ and $f\left(x\right)$ are the same.

But surprisingly I found the answer 'No'. Because of course in the case of $f\left(x\right)$:

$\left(x-2\right)\left(x-3\right)>0$

whereas in case of $g\left(x\right)$:

$\left(x-2\right)>0$ and $\left(x-3\right)>0$ individually. Which yielded two different domains for $f\left(x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)$.

So can't we simplify and write a function. For instance like the above case if we have

## $F\left(x\right)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$

Is it incorrect to write:

$F\left(x\right)=x+1$ ?

I know that the question is a bit silly. But it might clarify many of my basic doubts based on calculus.

Comment: The question isn't silly at all...

Comment: It depends on the domain of $F$. $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ has a smaller domain i.e. $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. So the following statement would be correct: $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$ when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: user42388- Isn't the domain R−{1}?

Comment: user157716 - thanks :)